# perl storing hash in %ENV

Tags: perl, hash, env

I want to (ab-)use the global %ENV to store a hash.  This seems to work differently for %ENV than for ordinary hashes.  in the program below, the `$ENV{myhash}` still contains `'myhash' => 'HASH(0x7ffad8807380)'` and the `%ahash` is still around.  is it possible to convert the hex address back to point at its location, instead of just containing the string?  I guess I could serialize and unserialize the hash instead.  what is the right way to do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use common::sense;
use Data::Dumper;

my %QENV = ( nohash => 'noh' );
my %ahash= ( hv1 => 'htext1', hv2 => 'htext2' );
$QENV{'myhash'} = \%ahash;
print "works: ". Dumper(\%QENV)."\n\n\n";


$ENV{'myhash'} = \%ahash;
print "fails: ". Dumper(\%ENV)."\n";
```

Comment: no. system environment variables have nothing to do with perl. you cannot store perl data structures in them. You have to serialize to plain text, then store that serialized text in the var.

Comment: what is the reasoning behind wanting to do this?

Comment: a convenient way to pass a global variable around many different modules, etc.  for example, if I store the http session hash in %ENV in one module, now any other perl module or routine can check whether an http session exists.  just an execute of a just `defined($ENV{'myhash'} and ...', doing different things depending on whether we have it or not.    I know the `no strict vars` trick.  makes sense or not?  but, on reflection, maybe not.  I thought %ENV did not inherit back up to the process itself.

Comment: you can set a flag in an env var and fetch that, but that won't work for a full session hash. why not just call into the main module and get its stored list of sessions, or store it in a file/db?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%ENV` is a magical hash. It reflects the process's environment. Reading from it reads from the environment, and writing to it changes the environment.

If you can guarantee the referenced variable is still alive (by it still being in scope or by it having its `REFCNT` increased), you can indeed create a reference to it from the address.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

use Inline C => <<'__EOS__';

   SV* _newRV(IV iv) {
      return newRV((SV*)iv);
   }

__EOS__

my %hash = ( a => 1, b => 2 );
my $ref = \%hash;
my $ref_string = "$ref";
my $addr = hex( ( $ref_string =~ /\((.*)\)/ )[0] );
my $ref2 = _newRV($addr);
print(Dumper($ref2));
```

I have no idea why you'd want to do this. It would not permit another process to access the data since one process can't access the memory of another.

Comment: darn (on the propagation back up).  I thought it was a neat trick to make it easy to inject a global variable.  and, yes, before anyone complains about globals, it can be useful.  `use 5.018' uses a global.  for this matter, the same can be said about %ENV.  it is a global.  I guess it will have to be the no strict vars instead with a new hash, which does not propagate back.  it was also a useful trick to learn.  thanks.

Comment: wut /// Don't know what you mean by "propagate up". Are you saying it can't be used to pass info from child to parent? True. It can't even be used to pass info from parent to child. /// Actually, `use 5.018` is lexically scoped, not global. /// What's with the anti-anti-global rant? Noone said you can't use globals. There's very rarely a reason to, but not never. They can be declared using `our` instead of `my`. /// Neither knowing that the number is an address nor using `newRV` to create a reference are tricks.

Comment: Could perhaps serialise the data structure as JSON, and retrieve it. But it's a bit of a hacky sort of IPC.

Comment: That would only work for passing down to the child, in which case you could just pass the JSON as an argument

Comment: I thought %ENV was the OS passing a copy of %ENV, not a reference to  %ENV (i.e., \%ENV).    changes would disappear at perl exit.   it would then be a central place for all global info, e.g., with %ENV = ( 'session' => [ ... ], %ENV). %ENV would have been the natural location IMHO to store globals for stuff that may or may not be loaded.  the other solutions seemed uglier and/or more complex.

Comment: Yes, but the same goes for ordinary variables. As for passing to a child, using an argument would be more straightforward than using the environment

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to share data. Here's an example I put out there often that shows how to store data in a JSON file, then retrieve it. JSON is cross-language, so the data can be used by many programming languages, not just Perl. Although this example is within a single script, imagine it being two different Perl applications:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use JSON;

my $file = 'data.json';

my %h = (
   foo => 'bar',
   raz => {
       ABC => 123,
       XYZ => [4, 5, 6],
   }
);

my $json = encode_json \%h;

# write the JSON to a file, and close it

open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;
print $fh $json;
close $fh or die $!;

# open the JSON file, and read it

open my $json_file, '<', $file or die $!;

my $read_json;

{
    local $/;
    $read_json = <$json_file>;
}

my $perl_hash = decode_json $read_json;
```